# select rows from table based on data from another table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, select

```
Mentor table
------------
name (varchar)
contact (int)
english (boolean)
french (boolean)
german (boolean)


Student table
-------------
name (varchar)
contact (int)
english (boolean)
french (boolean)
german (boolean)
```

I want to match mentor with student based on the languages, such that for example:

if mentor1 knows english and french, he will be matched with all students that know at least english or french.

```
mentor1 (english, french)
-------------------------
studentA (english); 
studentB (english, french); 
studentC (english, german);
studentD (english, french, german)
```

if mentor2 know german only, he will be matched with all students that know at least german. the students matched can know more than just german.

```
mentor2 (german)
----------------
studentC (english, german)
studentD (english, french, german)
```

normally i will just use a bunch of `if then else` to piece together a sql string but i am using `gridview` to display the data so i am not sure what can i do.

sample codes and tutorials are alway welcome.

edit: forgot to mention that the `mentor` table will also have columns such as `name` and `contact`. so the output on the `gridview` should be 1 row per `mentor`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*, s.name
FROM    dbo.Mentor m
JOIN    dbo.Student s
ON EXISTS 
(
    SELECT  x.LanguageID
    FROM    
    (
        SELECT 1 AS LanguageID WHERE s.english = 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 AS LanguageID WHERE s.french = 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 AS LanguageID WHERE s.german = 1
    ) x
    INTERSECT
    SELECT  y.LanguageID
    FROM    
    (
        SELECT 1 AS LanguageID WHERE m.english = 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 2 AS LanguageID WHERE m.french = 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 3 AS LanguageID WHERE m.german = 1
    ) y
)
ORDER BY m.name
```

Comment: modified the codes to suit my actual db and it works. didn't know `intersect` exist for sql. thx a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select
   m.MentorName
   , m.Language
   , s.StudentName
from Mentor as m
inner join Student as s
on (m.English = 1 and m.English = s.English)
    or (m.french = 1 and m.French = s.French)
    or (m.German = 1 and m.German = s.German);
```

This would be easier if you had your tables structured without field for each language but a record instead

```
Table: Mentor(MentorName, Language)
Rows:
Mentor1 | English
Mentor2 | Englisn
Mentor2 | French
```

Do the same for Students and then the query is:

```
Select
   m.MentorName
   , m.Language
   , s.StudentName

from Mentor as m
inner join Student as s
on m.Language = s.Language
```

The benefit here is if you add another language, it is purely data entry and no need to change table structure or your code, but that is not always an option.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, it makes sense. however i forgot to mention that the `mentor` table will also have other columns such as `contact` and `name`, which i want to display as well.